# What is the radius of the windows on BigSur?

Tags: windows, graphics, ui

I read [Apple's What's New in macOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/overview/whats-new-in-macos/) about BigSur, and they have mentioned about an increase in the window radius, but they have not mentioned anywhere about what the radius is.

> Throughout macOS 11, windows adopt visual touches that recall iOS interfaces. For example, windows integrate the sidebar, toolbar, and content areas, **use an increased corner radius**, and display lightweight controls.

In the past, the windows on macOS had a radius of [around 7px](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18689/radius-of-mac-os-x-windows). In BigSur, it is very clear that the radius of the corners has increased, but what is the exact radius of the windows?

Comment: I think you'd just have to do the same as the answer in your link and take a hand-made measurement.  Just create a box with a corner of X-radius until it matches the radius of the window in Big Sur.  You'll have your answer.

Comment: @Allan I would do that, but I unfortunately do not run BigSur. I tried finding screenshots on the web but they get too pixelated when zooming into the corners of the windows

Comment: The smaller radius of Catalina is way better. Hate this update. Catalina has way cleaner UI, I updated one macbook and try to avoid the update with the other as long as possible -.- Someone with an Apple account should make a feature request so the corner radius can be customized by the user.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from analyzing a screenshot from a MacBook Pro 15 Inch: 18px

Comment: Actually, 18px would be the diameter, or radius when measured in @2x resolution. From what I've experimented, the radius is 9. Hope this helps.